# Selenium with Python 3.5 and Chrome - failed to click element located via xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

I have a script which gets me info from Polish Avon's website. So essentially every month they change prices, and to make my girl's life easier I just download the prices to have a look up table in excel.

Anyways, so I have the script which navigates to this website:
https://www.avon.pl/szukaj/po-kodzie-produktu/

Once the page is loaded it enters a number between 00000 and 99999 into the search box, which I find using xpath:

`find_box_path = '//*[@id="ShopByProductNumber"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/input'`

Only some of the codes are valid, so if the search is successful, the script will click on the item, which opens in a new window and processes the information, if nothing is found it moves on to the next number. The script checks for the xpath to figure out if the code is valid or not. The following exctract would click on the element and open a new tab:

```
#   ------------        click the product       ------------
find_item_text_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(find_text_path))
find_item_text_element.click()
time.sleep(0.4)
```

The find_text_path variable is declared earlier as:

```
find_text_path = '//*[@id="ShopByProductNumber"]/div[2]/div[3]/p/a'
```

The interesting bit, is that for more than a year, my script worked like a charm. Only 2 days ago the script was running, I got through maybe 25000 combinations until it stooped. From that point, when the script gets to the bit above, it shuts down and resets. I understand why it resets - that is intended - but I have no idea why it won't click on the element. The IDE doesn't show any error.

I use XPather to find the xpaths, and the one above is a valid xpath. And as I said it work fine until now. I understand that website itself could have done something to prevent automation, but I don't see the problem. Can anyone see/point out the problem? Maybe some workarounds?

[Location of both elements in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAXJ2.png)

**EDIT:**

The issue was resolved.  The zoom in my chrome profile I was using, was set to 105% instead of 100%. This cause the webdriver to click wrong spot on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the specific html code which is causing the issue? I'm not able to find it on the website. Maybe the element you're trying to reach is now included in a frame, but I can only suppose without the html.

Comment: I actually figured it out couple days ago. As it turns out, the zoom was set to 105% instead of 100%. This cause the webdriver to click the wrong spot on the page. I've noticed that during my debug, when I decided to use 'context_click()' instead of regular 'click()'. Should have edited my question once I've found the issue.